# How to count paragraphs?

Tags: python-3.x

How do you counts paragraphs from a file after string.read()?

I have no Idea where to start.

```
THE Mississippi is well worth reading about. It is not a commonplace
river, but on the contrary is in all ways remarkable. Considering the
Missouri its main branch, it is the longest river in the world--four
thousand three hundred miles. It seems safe to say that it is also the
crookedest river in the world, since in one part of its journey it uses
up one thousand three hundred miles to cover the same ground that the
crow would fly over in six hundred and seventy-five. It discharges three
times as much water as the St. Lawrence, twenty-five times as much
as the Rhine, and three hundred and thirty-eight times as much as the
Thames. No other river has so vast a drainage-basin: it draws its water
supply from twenty-eight States and Territories; from Delaware, on the
Atlantic seaboard, and from all the country between that and Idaho on
the Pacific slope--a spread of forty-five degrees of longitude. The
Mississippi receives and carries to the Gulf water from fifty-four
subordinate rivers that are navigable by steamboats, and from some
hundreds that are navigable by flats and keels. The area of its
drainage-basin is as great as the combined areas of England, Wales,
Scotland, Ireland, France, Spain, Portugal, Germany, Austria, Italy,
and Turkey; and almost all this wide region is fertile; the Mississippi
valley, proper, is exceptionally so.

It is a remarkable river in this: that instead of widening toward its
mouth, it grows narrower; grows narrower and deeper. From the junction
of the Ohio to a point half way down to the sea, the width averages a
mile in high water: thence to the sea the width steadily diminishes,
until, at the 'Passes,' above the mouth, it is but little over half
a mile. At the junction of the Ohio the Mississippi's depth is
eighty-seven feet; the depth increases gradually, reaching one hundred
and twenty-nine just above the mouth.
```

For example a file that has 2 paragraphs how can I loop through and count each paragraph? What reference do I use. I can't use \n so I'm unsure what to do. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

i personnaly use `\n`, here's how i do it

```py
def par_counter(txt):
    txt = txt.strip() # to remove empty lines at the beginning and end
    return len([i for i in txt if i == '\n'])
```

if don't want to use `\n` to count and use empty lines (between paragraphs) instead, you can do this :

```py
def par_counter(txt):
    lines = txt.strip().splitlines() # to remove empty lines at the beginning and end   
    emptylines = [e for e in lines if e.strip() == ''] # find empty lines (line between paragraph and another)

    # return nb lines + 1 because if there are N empty lines, then we have N+1 paragraphs
    return len(emptylines) + 1
```